# Saving dataframes to .csv and create folder without specifying the file path

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, path, save

I am trying to find a way to save a few dataframes to .csv format as part of a ML routine I am designing in Python. Since this is composed of multiple steps, I would like to create folders in which to save dataframes as part of the code. Since the `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` does not allow you to create folders, I have found this solution using `os`:

```
import os

import pandas as pd
    
outname = 'name.csv'
    
outdir = './dir'
if not os.path.exists(outdir):
    os.mkdir(outdir)
    
fullname = os.path.join(outdir, outname)    
    
df.to_csv(fullname)
```

However, this method requires you to specify the directory path. Since I would like the code to run on multiple devices without the need to rewrite the specific `outdir` each time, I am looking for a way to create a folder within the current Python working directory (whichever that may be on each device) in which to save the .csv file without the need to write down the path.

Comment: That path is already relative to the current working directory. Do you want to generate unique paths each time? Then maybe something like a timestamp. Current working directory may be a bad idea. If its run through a GUI, current working directory may be a system path. Maybe create a path based on the user home directory?

Comment: I see your point and it may indeed be a problem. Is there a way to 'generally' specify a path such as the computer desktop?

Comment: Mostly. You could use `Path.home()` from the pathlib module to get your home directory. maybe add your app name to it. So on Windows and other systems that have a Desktop folder, `app_path = Path.home()/"Desktop"/"YourAppHere"` and then `app_path.mkdir(exists_ok=True)`. That may need to be tweeked for different OS's. And sometimes user accounts don't have a home directory - servers are like that sometimes.

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks, I was not aware of Path.home(), that definitely solved the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to specify the full path, just the relative path.

Try:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
outname = 'name.csv'

outdir = 'dir'
if not os.path.exists(outdir):
    os.mkdir(outdir)
    
df.to_csv(f"{outdir}/{outname}")
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__file__) variable that contains the full path to the script. `__file__` will only work when you run it as a script and not in an interpreter.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
outname = 'name.csv'

outdir = 'dir'
fullname = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), outdir)
if not os.path.exists(fullname):
    os.mkdir(fullname)
    
df.to_csv(f"{fullname}/{outname}")
```

Comment: `dir` and `./dir` are the same relative path. Its usually not a good idea to store data in the same directory as your scripts (if they are installed, it may be read-only and shared by other accounts on the same system).